# SQL STUFF DATETIME Doesn't return all values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use the STUFF function to combine the text for specific rows into one cell. It works fine for VARCHAR values but when I use STUFF with a DATETIME value I receive an error: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."
I tried to cast the value but it does not return the values that I was expecting.

What I am trying to return in each CreatedDate row would be something like

> " Mar 29 2016  9:42AM,  Mar 31 2016  9:42AM,  Mar 31 2016  9:43AM"

but it is only displaying one of the values.
Here is part of my query:

```
SELECT
[KEY] 
,STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [Code] FROM #tempTable t WHERE t.[KEY]=tt.[KEY] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [Code] 
,STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + CAST([CreatedDate] AS NVARCHAR(100)) FROM #tempTable t WHERE t.[KEY]=tt.[KEY] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS [CreatedDate] 
FROM #tempTable tt
Group by KEY
```

Comment: What happens if you forget the `stuff` function and simply select `cast (createdDate as nvarchar (100))`

Comment: can you give your sample created date values

Comment: I have a key value 12345, and that specific key value has three records. The date from the first record for key 12345 is Mar 29 2016 9:42AM, the date from the second record is Mar 31 2016 9:42AM, and the date from the third record is Mar 31 2016 9:43AM.

Comment: Is there another part of the query that might be trying to convert from a `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME`?

Comment: no that is the only CAST that I have in my query.

Comment: You don't need a `CAST` to have a type conversion. Using `CONVERT` causes explicit type conversion and SQL Server will perform _implicit_ type conversion when you use mismatched data types within expressions. I'm guessing that you are fighting an implicit conversion elsewhere in the query.

Comment: `when I use STUFF with a DATETIME value I receive an error`.. `but it is only displaying one of the values`... so which one is it.. can't be both

Comment: @Jamie I state that there is an error, then I CAST the value and only one value is displayed.

Comment: @BrettKB gotcha.. you shouldnt need 100 len.. should be able to just use `convert(varchar, [CreatedDate])`.. if only one date appears, then you are only getting one date in your query

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is some part of the query which is not in the question..below is repro.further stuff wont cause you any issues..

--this works

```
declare  @dt table
(
id datetime
)
insert into @dt
select 'Mar 29 2016 9:42AM' union
select 'Mar 31 2016 9:42AM' union select  'Mar 31 2016 9:43AM'

select  id,stuff((select ','+ convert(varchar,id) from @dt
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from @dt
```

--this doesnt work obviously and you are not doing this in your query..

```
declare  @dt table
(
id datetime
)
insert into @dt
select 'Mar 29 2016 9:42AM' union
select 'Mar 31 2016 9:42AM' union select  'Mar 31 2016 9:43AM'

select  id,stuff((select ','+ id from @dt
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from @dt
```

there seems to be some place (not shown in your question) where you are storing datetime as varchar and while converting it to datetime ,it is failing

Stuff doesnt cause any values to be truncated,if you are seeing less values,you should look at your join columns individually